# Почему не подключается конкретный шрифт?

Tags: css, шрифты

Почему-то не подключается конкретный шрифт в CSS.

Пример рабочего кода:

```css
font-family: 'Open Sans';
src: url('fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf'),
     url('fonts/Open_Sans/opensans-semibold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('fonts/Open_Sans/opensans-semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

А эта часть отказывется работать:

```
font-family: 'Poppins';
src: url('fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Medium.ttf')
     url('fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Medium.eot');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

Уже конвертировал в разные форматы, проверял пути и т.д.
Что характерно, в режиме разработчика стиль отображается. Текст на латинице, так что конфликт с кириллицей отпадает.
Как видите, имеется рабочий шрифт, лежащий в соседней папке, и подключенный абсолютно таким же способом. И он работает.

Comment: OpenSans может работать, потому что установлен у вас в системе, а Попинс не срабатывает из-за неверного пути (например, не хватает слэша в начале).

Comment: Зачем вам так подключать, используйте google fonts.

Comment: Всё сделал через google fonts. Open Sans не работает, если неправильно задать директорию или отключить woff и woff2. Ошибка указания пути маловероятна, так как пользуюсь плагинами для этого.

Вроде проблема с подключением решена, но остался вопрос. Почему одни шрифты работают, а другие нет?

Comment: https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts - должно помочь, выбираете шрифт, настраиваете и скачиваете

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую взять шрифт с Google Fontes. Инструкция:

1. Выбираем шрифт с сайта https://fonts.google.com/
2. Выбираем **семейство** шрифтов (например, Roboto)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Выбираем **шрифты**[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Копируем import и вставляем в css файл[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. Теперь мы можем использовать эти шрифты. В моём случае для вызова шрифта нужно написать:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');
p{
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; /*семья*/
font-weight: Regular 400; /*конкретный шрифт, один из тех, что мы импортируем*/
}
```

```html
<body>
<p>stackoverflow</p>
</body>
```

Не загружайте много шрифтов, от этого сайт начинает долго загружаться

Полезная статья о шрифтах на htmlbook: http://htmlbook.ru/css/font